# Bit manipulation for identity property

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given an integer and either 1 or 0, I'd like to be able to get either the integer or 0 using only bitwise operators. That means no if statements, conditionals, etc. Basically integer * i. Two's complement system!

I have been working for a while and it is tricky. Here are my failed attempts:
Edit: ints are unsigned

```
unsigned int x = 24; // To change
unsigned int i = 0; // identity

((~i) | x) // if i  = 0, ~i returns 111...1    || (111...1 | x) = 111...1
          //  else ~i returns 000...1          || (000...1 | x) = x (+1 sometimes)
```

The code I have above makes it so if i is 1, then I get the identity (only sometimes), and if i is 0, then I get -1. I'd like it so if i is 1, I get the identity, and if i is 0, I get 0. Thanks!

Comment: first of all bit-twiddling is to be done on unsigned types. Secondly: this will be very much easier if addition and subtraction is allowed...

Comment: addition is allowed, subtraction is not, though with addition being allowed it is the same thing i think?

Comment: Would you mind to show us an example of the desired output?

Comment: @thebusybee Define `f` such that `f(0, x) = 0` and `f(1, x) = x` for all integers `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
i & -x
```

If `x` is zero, you get `i & 0` which is zero. If `x` is one, you get `i & UINT_MAX` which is `i`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch! The - operation was unavailable so I completely forgot I could invert things using ~x + 1.

Comment: @Steven Er, did you cimment on the wrong answer there? Addition is allowed by unary negation isn't?

Comment: addition is allowed but negation wasn't. If we wanted to negate, we needed to write it out ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using

```
~i + 1u & x
```

`~0u` produces `UINT_MAX` (all bits 1):

```
1111...1111
```

Adding 1 goes back to 0:

```
0000...0000
```

On the other hand, `~1u` produces `UINT_MAX - 1`:

```
1111...1110
```

Adding 1 then gives `UINT_MAX` (all bits 1):

```
1111...1111
```

These are perfect bit masks to use with `&`: `(0 & x) == 0` and `(UINT_MAX & x) == x`.